# Can I include multiple tasks in include_tasks from tasks/main.yml?

Tags: ansible

I would like to include multiple variables and tasks from my main task file, however I receive the following error when I attempt to do so:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>
```

...

```
The offending line appears to be:


- name: install and configure [application]
  ^ here
```

Here's my tasks/main.yml file in the role:

```
---

- name: install and configure [application]
  include_vars:
    - dependencies.yml
    - directories.yml
    - installations.yml
  include_tasks:
    - pre-setup.yml
    - [application-23].yml
    - database.yml
    - [application-4].yml
    - update.yml
    - additional-components.yml
    - ldap.yml
    - test.yml
```

I suspect my formatting or syntax is invalid but I'm not precisely sure how to fix it.

I'd prefer to make my variables available globally at this time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. An ansible task can only do a single action, i.e. contain only one module call
2. The [`include_tasks` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html) does not accept a list in the `file`/free-form parameter, only one single file name
3. The [`include_vars` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) can eventually read several files if you load a full directory with the `dir` option.
4. There are filenames that look a little weird in your included tasks and might cause errors. Do your file names really contain square brackets (`[]`) ? They are markers for lists and might be interpreted as such.

From the info I have so far, this is all I can propose to fix your current failing task:

```yaml
- name: Include variables
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - dependencies.yml
    - directories.yml
    - installations.yml

- name: Play needed tasks in order
  include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - pre-setup.yml
    - application-23.yml
    - database.yml
    - application-4.yml
    - update.yml
    - additional-components.yml
    - ldap.yml
    - test.yml
```

Meanwhile, I suggest you take some time to read the doc a little more and maybe get familiar with the concept of [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) as the above does not look like a good design at first glance.

Comment: i had a problem with this since if theres a failure on the first item, then it seems that the rest of the items may not run, didnt in my case. (using with_items instead of loop in my case).  in a loop of 3 items, the first one failed, last two didnt even run.

Comment: @blamb this is the expected behavior by default in Ansible. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure

Answer (score 0):

You could just include or even better import all the tasks through a list without specifying the name of the task:

```
---
- import_tasks: pre-setup.yml
- import_tasks: [application-23].yml
- import_tasks: database.yml
- import_tasks: [application-4].yml
- import_tasks: update.yml
- import_tasks: additional-components.yml
- import_tasks: ldap.yml
- import_tasks: test.yml
```